# Address validation in magento 2 checkout page and address book

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, validation, shipping-address

I am facing an issue with invalid address inputs by customers. I have implemented paypal integration in my magento 2 site. If the user enter an invalid address, paypal is rejecting the payments.

I have searched out for a address validation plugin and nothing found. And someone are too expensive to buy. Can anyone suggest me some address validation plugins for address validation in magento2?

Or how can I write my own validation plugin there, I have a state table and a zipcode table(this table contains city too).

I tried with https://github.com/Nabooru/module-address-validation-core but I don't get the list of adapters to check with.

My magento version is "2.1.2" and  I need a city, state and zipcode combination validation.

Comment: Let me know if you want to validate the zipcode with respect to country.

Comment: I have only US shipping. So only validate address in the US. I need a city, state and zipcode combination

Comment: Use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)  They allow 2,500 requests per day and you can pay for more.  It will take an address and give you very detailed information on it and provide validation if you code it into your application.